# Qt 6.5.3 : Can't change QWidget position

Tags: c++, qt, position, qwidget

I have problem with my QWidget window which I can't update position.
I don't use the Ui tool.

I've tried:

```
    QRect           screenGeometry;
    int             x;
    int             y;

    screenGeometry = QApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
    x = (screenGeometry.width() - aw_.width()) / 2;
    y = (screenGeometry.height() - aw_.height()) / 2;
    aw_.move(x, y);
    aw_.show();
```

but the window doesn't move.

I also tried :

```
    QRect           screenGeometry;
    int             x;
    int             y;

    screenGeometry = QApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
    x = screenGeometry.center().x();
    y = screenGeometry.center().y();
    aw_.setUpdatesEnabled(true);
    aw_.setGeometry(x, y, 400, 300);
    QApplication::processEvents();
    aw_.show();
```

There the size of the window changed but remains stuck a random point on the screen.

I also tried to create a new project with a Ui and I saw in the Design panel that the values of  X and Y of the geometry property can't be changed (they're disabled) but not width and height.

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: swap show and move? (also either move your widget to primaryScreen or use widget's screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
I'm using Debian running with Wayland which doesn't allow windows to move by themselves.

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).